# Minecraft crashes with exit code -1073741571

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When starting Minecraft, it immediately crashes with this crash log:

```
[Launcher] Starting Minecraft 1.12.2...
[Launcher] Launching in: C:\Users\Jaideep\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft
[Launcher] Processing post-launch actions. Assist launch: true
====================================================================
> [19:32:19] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Jaideepndhruv
> [19:32:29] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
Here I am!
[VersionManager] Refreshing versions locally...
[VersionManager] Versions has been refreshed (94 ms)
[TlauncherManager] before clearLibrary 
[TlauncherManager] after clearLibrary 
[Launcher] Launcher exited.
[Launcher] Minecraft closed with exit code: -1073741571
```

What can I do to make Minecraft work?

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest driver version 378.66 (or later) from http://www.geforce.com/drivers

Source and more info: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-112780